# A service is failing to build with the command '/bin/sh -c npm ci'

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am setting up a container that will host my react client code but the build fails on the local machine with an exit code of 1. How should I go about troubleshooting this error?

I have tried restarting the docker-machine and docker clients.

docker-machine version 0.16.0, build 702c267f

docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown

Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

client:
    build: 
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports: 
      - 3007:3000
    environment: 
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on: 
      - users
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM node:11.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am expecting the service "client" to successfully build but I keep getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/enzyme/-/enzyme-3.10.0.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-15T05_55_38_024Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'client' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm ci' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: `npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN`means DNS Error

Comment: How can I solve this? I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error `npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN` means a DNS error I suggest you to do one of the follwong:

build your image using the `host` network:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

client:
    build: 
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      network: host
    volumes: 
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports: 
      - 3007:3000
    environment: 
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on: 
      - users
```

or add `dns` setting to your `daemon.json` file:

```
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}
```

Comment: It has worked. Thank you. One question though, what about when I deploy it to a vps. Should I use the same setting?

Comment: it depends on the host/docker configs . but it will not harm if you use them again